# Iterate over files containing string in file name and copy to directory, parse date from file

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, printing

I'm trying to copy all files in a directory with a specific file name to a different directory. However, when I try to print the file name or copy the file over, the file name is printed as blank line / the file to be copied is considered blanks. The c parameter is passed in through the command line.

I know there are matches for the parameter, so why is it evaluated as blank?

Code:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
set -x
printf  'Processing option arguments:\n'
while getopts ":b:c:e:" arg; do
  case "${arg}" in
    b) b="$OPTARG"; echo "\$b is $b";;
    c) c="$OPTARG"; echo "\$c is $c";;
    e) e="$OPTARG"; echo "\$e is $e";;
  esac
done
printf 'Done.\n\n'

shift $((OPTIND - 1))

printf 'Remaining (non-option) arguments:\n'
printf '%s\n' "$@"

cd "/opt/data"

ssh MyHost << EOF

rm -rf testDirectory
mkdir testDirectory

find . -type f -name '*$c*' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; 
do
  cp -r $file /testDirectory
done
EOF
```

Output:

```
cp: missing destination file operand after `/testDirectory'
Try `cp --help' for more information.
```

calling the script like this:

```bsh
bash script.sh -b 06-30-20-18-10 -e 06-30-20-23-59 -c fileNameToMatch
```

Edit: I am trying to parse the file name:
Test_07_24_18_09_53.log 
to be: 1807180953
 the format of YearMonthDayHourMinute 
 How do I parse the date like this? 
I am trying to use SED but it evaluates as blank: f=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/[a-zA-Z./]*//g')
>
month=$(echo "$f" | cut -d- -f1)

day=$(echo "$f" | cut -d- -f2) 

year=$(echo "$f" | cut -d- -f3)

Comment: Please see [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting)

Comment: You want to expand `$c` in the heredoc, but there are some values you **don't** want to expand, like `$file` -- you need to add some backslashes to escape those variables

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/users/10127/glenn-jackman), you have used the unquoted `EOF` in order to allow `$c` to be expanded to its value in the local shell before being passed to the remote shell via ssh. That **also** allows `$file` (and `$'\0'` - but that expands to the same thing in either shell) to be expanded locally - where it is presumably empty. Since you didn't double-quote it, the copy command becomes

```
cp -r  /testDirectory
```

so `/testDirectory` becomes the cp command's *SOURCE* parameter, and its *DEST* is missing.

To prevent premature evaluation of `$file` you can backslash-escape the `$`. You should also double-quote the expansion:

```
find . -type f -name '*$c*' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; 
do
  cp -r "\$file" /testDirectory
done
```

You *could* also backslash-escape `$'\0'` or simply replace it with the empty string `''` which works as well for null-delimited data.

However it would be more efficient to avoid the remote shell loop altogether, using GNU cp's `-t DIRECTORY SOURCE` format:

```
find . -type f -name '*$c*' -exec cp -t /testDirectory {} +
```

Comment: thank you that helped a lot... still have 1 other problem though... I want to parse the date to be -> "YearMonthDayHourMinute", from the format: 04_04_22_16_18, which is in the "\$file" name... 

previously I was doing <br>month=$(echo "$file" | cut -d_ -f2)
   day=$(echo "$file" | cut -d_ -f3) 

but changing 'EOF' to 'EOF' caused that not to work..
I tried again using "$file", but it still is not parsing out the date. Do I need the backslash here?

Comment: @usr_tt I'd suggest doing all that kind of processing **outside** of the heredoc, and simply using `$name`, `$day` etc. **inside** the heredoc in just the same way as you are currently using `$c`